# Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it. sql android

Tags: java, android, sql

```
public class recordd extends Activity{


    Button b;
    int count;
    String date;
    Record record;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.record);

        int calo =getIntent().getIntExtra("cal", 0);

        TextView TEXT =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.record);


        record= new Record(this);
        db= record.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO tab VALUES (null, 'calo' ,null);");

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(cal) FROM tab ", null);


        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            int addr = cursor.getInt(0);
            String addrrr = Integer.toString(addr);
            String abc = cursor.getString(2);
        }
```

i get the 'calo' from the last activity. and then put that number to the sql table which name is tab. and then make a cursor to sum the cal which has the information for the calo. 
but there is a problem .

> "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col
>   2 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly
>   before accessing data from it."

and this is the more information for the table creation.

```
public class Record extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydb.db"; 
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; 




    public Record(Context context){

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }




    @Override

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE tab ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                +"cal INTEGER, timestamp DATE DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime')));");
    }

    @Override 
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tab;");
        onCreate(db);
    }



}
```

I have dumped for days

Comment: Based on the `SQL` query, the cursor will contains only one row as a result and this row will have only one column. The problem is that you're trying to get the third column `cursor.getString(2);` which doesn't exist.

Comment: i forgot the problem line. according to the log , String abc = cursor.getString(2); has this problem "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 2 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it."

Comment: thanks  titus . then  how i can get the sum from the sql table....

Comment: i thought the table will be created like this - 1 100  2016/05/22  -  2  150 2016/5/23 -  3 100 2016/5/29    and want to sum the second part...

Comment: In the code that you've posted, `addrrr` will contains the sum of the `cal` column of the `tab` table. Just remove this line `String abc = cursor.getString(2);` and it should work.

Comment: can i ask a quesiton ? then if i want to get the whole thing for the table...i should write down select * from tab . and if there is records for 5 days... i can use cursor 5 times?

Comment: @applefine *"use cursor 5 times"* is confusing terminology. According to your `INSERT` statement, there are only 3 columns in `tab`, so if you execute `select * from tab` and there are 5 records, then you can loop on the cursor the way you do, retrieve ("use"?) 3 values numbered 0-2 for the columns, and the loop will iterate 5 times. In total, you will be calling a `get` method 15 times, and `moveToNext()` 6 times (last call returning false). And of course the ever-so-important `close()` call. Never forget that one.

Comment: You didn't closed your cursor after while loop. Add db.close() after while loop.

Comment: @Titus thanks for your help ^^

Comment: @Andreas thanks for your help i will try ^^

Comment: @Azharosws i also never forget to close a cursor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar error and provide this answer to my similar issue in case someone comes across this question with the same issue.

I am using SQLiteAssetHelper and had my SQL call setup as follows:

```
 public Cursor getStateData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    String [] sqlSelect = {"0 _id", "state", "iconone" };
    String sqlTables = "Reefs";
    qb.setTables(sqlTables);
    qb.setDistinct(true);
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    return c;
}
```

I added the call to the second column of data which was in column 6 in my SQL table, so assumed I should do the call as follows:

```
 do
    {
        dataprovider = new StateDataProvider(statesData.getString(1), statesData.getString(6));
        arrayList.add(dataprovider);
    } while (statesData.moveToNext());
```

Not so, you dont make the call to the column number 6 but two the second sqlSelect call as follows:

```
 do
    {
        dataprovider = new StateDataProvider(statesData.getString(1), statesData.getString(2));
        arrayList.add(dataprovider);
    } while (statesData.moveToNext());
```

Hope it saves someone many fruitless hours I spent on this error.